# xUnit and Watin cleanup

Tags: c#, watin, xunit, resource-cleanup

I have some test cases using xUnit and Watin. To make all Facts in the class share the same instance of IE, I had created a singleton class so the first test will launch a new IE instance, and the following tests will use the same instance.

After all Facts finish, the IE instance is still running. I just wonder how to close IE after all tests in the class finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For this purpose your class with tests need to implement [IUserFixture](https://xunit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Comparisons#note3) interface.
I'll provide the example which solves your needs and demonstrates `xunit` life-cycle model:

```
public class MyTestClass : IUseFixture<WatinFixture>, IDisposable
{
    private WatinFixture _data;

    public void SetFixture(WatinFixture data)
    {
        _data = data;
        Console.WriteLine("setting data for test");
    }

    public MyTestClass()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in constructor of MyTestClass");
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Fact1()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in fact1. IE is '{0}'", _data.ReferenceToIE);
        // use _data.ReferenceToIE here
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Fact2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in fact2. IE is '{0}'", _data.ReferenceToIE);
        // use _data.ReferenceToIE here
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("in Dispose of MyTestClass");
    }
}

public class WatinFixture : IDisposable
{
    public string ReferenceToIE = null;

    public WatinFixture()
    {
        // start IE here
        Console.WriteLine("Starting IE ...");
        ReferenceToIE = "If you see this string - then browser reference is not empty.";
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        // close IE here
        Console.WriteLine("Closing IE ...");
        ReferenceToIE = null;
        }
    }
```

Output:

> Starting IE ...
>   in constructor of MyTestClass
>   setting data for test
>   in fact1. IE is 'If you see this string - then browser reference is not empty.'
>   in Dispose of MyTestClass
>   in constructor of MyTestClass
>   setting data for test
>   in fact2. IE is 'If you see this string - then browser reference is not empty.'
>   in Dispose of MyTestClass
>   Closing IE ...

Comment: I read similar codes in xUnit doc, but not as clear as your example demonstrating the life cycle. Now I don't need to construct singleton though I need to make sure lazy instantiation of the browser.